# Try to retrieve data from a called sub

Tags: excel, vba

First, my apologize because it's my first vba code. :)

I try to retrieve the Month Name in a sub when calling another one, which uses a case condition.
But the Month Name variable stays empty.

Can you tell me why ?

Here is my code :

```
enter code here

Sub RetrieveMonthName(MoisDeFacturation As Integer)

Dim MonthName As String

Select Case MoisDeFacturation
   Case Is = 1
      MonthName = "Janvier"
   Case Is = 2
      MonthName = "Février"
   Case Is = 3
      MonthName = "Mars"
   Case Is = 4
      MonthName = "Avril"
   Case Is = 5
      MonthName = "Mai"
   Case Is = 6
      MonthName = "Juin"
   Case Is = 7
      MonthName = "Juillet"
   Case Is = 8
      MonthName = "Août"
   Case Is = 9
      MonthName = "Septembre"
   Case Is = 10
      MonthName = "Octobre"
   Case Is = 11
      MonthName = "Novembre"
   Case Is = 12
      MonthName = "Décembre"
   Case Else
      MsgBox ("Sortie du programme, le chiffre " & MoisDeFacturation & " que vous avez 
renseigné ne correspond pas à un mois de l'année")
      Exit Sub
End Select

End Sub


Sub AddAFacture()


Dim InvoicingMonth As Integer
Dim MonthName As String

InvoicingMonth = 5
RetrieveMonthName (InvoicingMonth)
MsgBox ("" & MonthName & "")


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to declare `RetrieveMonthName` as function rather than sub.

Comment: Please be kinder to yourself.  Your function RetrieveMonthName is essentially reproducing what a collection (or better still - a scripting.dictionary) will do for you.

Comment: Side note, `Case Is = 1` can be simplified to `Case 1`.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your answers. 
@Harun, I already tried with a function instead of a sub but it didn't work too...

Comment: @Freeflow : I didn't know th scripting.dictionnary. I will have a look on that

Comment: @Mathieu : tx for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use your function you need to return a value like that

```
Option Explicit

Function RetrieveMonthName(MoisDeFacturation As Integer) As String

    Dim MonthName As String   ' This varaible is locally scoped and not visible outside the function

    Select Case MoisDeFacturation
        Case Is = 1
            MonthName = "Janvier"
        Case Is = 2
            MonthName = "Février"
        Case Is = 3
            MonthName = "Mars"
        Case Is = 4
            MonthName = "Avril"
        Case Is = 5
            MonthName = "Mai"
        Case Is = 6
            MonthName = "Juin"
        Case Is = 7
            MonthName = "Juillet"
        Case Is = 8
            MonthName = "Août"
        Case Is = 9
            MonthName = "Septembre"
        Case Is = 10
            MonthName = "Octobre"
        Case Is = 11
            MonthName = "Novembre"
        Case Is = 12
            MonthName = "Décembre"
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Sortie du programme, le chiffre " & MoisDeFacturation & " que vous avez renseigné ne correspond pas à un mois de l'année")
            Exit Function
    End Select
    ' retunr a value
    RetrieveMonthName = MonthName

End Function


Sub AddAFacture()

    Dim InvoicingMonth As Integer
    Dim MonthName As String

    InvoicingMonth = 5
    ' assin value to the locally scoped varaible MontNname (not visible in the function!)
    MonthName = RetrieveMonthName(InvoicingMonth)
    MsgBox ("" & MonthName & "")

End Sub
```

Of course it is easier to use functions coming with VBA resp. Excel which will give you the same result.

You only need this code

```
Sub AddAFactureA()

    Dim InvoicingMonth As Integer
    Dim mName As String

    InvoicingMonth = 5
        
    mName = MonthName(InvoicingMonth)
    
    MsgBox ("" & mName & "")

End Sub
```

As you used in your code a variable `MonthName`  in your cocde you hid the VBA function [MonthName](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/monthname-function) in your code which means you prevented yourself from using it.

Comment: Thanks @Storax, it works and now I understantd why it didn't work ;)

However, for your second option (AddAFactureA), how can it work while it does not call the function ?

Comment: `MonthName` is a built-in VBA function. Please followi the link and have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Danke @Storax für alles. Auf Wiedersehen ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You no need to declare additional function. You can achieve it like below.

```
Sub AddAFacture()
Dim InvoicingMonth As Integer
Dim MonthName As String

InvoicingMonth = 5
MonthName= Format(DateSerial(Year(Date()),InvoicingMonth,1),"mmmm")
MsgBox MonthName

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd add an if to check if the number is between 1-12 there.

Comment: If OP needs to validate month no then can use IF statement to check either month no between 1 to 12.

Comment: It actually is in the OP's code:  `Case Else
      MsgBox ("Sortie du programme, le chiffre " & MoisDeFacturation & " que vous avez 
renseigné ne correspond pas à un mois de l'année")`